# Automatically send post data to php using jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using WordPress 3.3.1 to grab the post_id from this line,

```
<div class="mppt_postid"><b>'.$post_id.'</b></div>
```

and then use jQuery script below to send the post_id number back to a WordPress php file on page load using $_POST['postid'] with AJAX, and then replace the post_id number with the data returned by the php script, which is another number (the visitor count). The jQuery script below is not working, and I am not sure how to trigger .post to automatically send the data when the page is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var postid = $('div.mppt_postid').attr('b');
    jQuery.post(mppt_ajax_script.ajaxurl, postid.serialize()
    , function(data) {
        jQuery('.mppt_postid').replaceWith(data);
    }
    );
}); // end ready
```

Comment: .post() is equal to .ajax() and .post() does not work under older versions of IE.  try to stick with .ajax()

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use ajax.  The post id is available during the page load via the $post->ID.  You can send this to a function that gets and returns the visitor count.

```
function get_visitor_count($id)
{
   //do your magic to get the visitor info
   return $visitor_count;
}
```

Then replace your original code with

```
<div class="mppt_postid"><b><?php echo get_visitor_count($post->ID); ?></b></div>
```

If you need to update the count via AJAX change your code to

```
var postid = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>;
```

Comment: The page is cached with Bat Cache, so a PHP function won't execute on every page load.

Comment: If that plugin is server side caching without allowing php to execute on each page load, I would not use that plug in.  The 200ms gained on page load time is not enough of a trade off to have to now use server and client side scripting to get around this (AJAX & jQuery).  You are better off using client side caching and mod_pagespeed for server side caching.  This allows for static content to be cached and dynamic content(what you have) to be processed much more efficiently.